# Генерация css файла gulp-ом из less файлов в twitter-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Хочу собрать свой css из исходников twitter-bootstrap less файлов. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
gulp.task('bootstrap', function(){
    gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/less/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Выдает ошибку:

> @alert-padding is undefined in file
>   /home/www/blog.loc/web/laravel/bower_components/bootstrap/less/alerts.less
>   line no. 10

Что нужно дописать в gulp-файл, чтоб все срослось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Gulp* тянет все файлы в порядке их расположения в папке (по алфавиту), где одним из первых идет файл *alerts.less*, в нем собственно и находится переменная `@alert-padding`. Однако все переменные объявляются в *variables.less*. Одним вариантом будет передача в *Gulp* одного файла, в котором явно указан порядок включения компонентов - собственно так делает сам *Bootstrap* - [файл bootstrap.less из репозитория Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/bootstrap.less):

```
// bootstrap.less - фрагменты файла

// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// ...

@import "alerts.less";
@import "progress-bars.less";
@import "media.less";

// ...
```

Т.е. чтобы просто врчную собрать *Bootstrap*, достаточно в *Gulp* передать сам файл *bootstrap.less*:

```
gulp.task('bootstrap', function(){
    gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Либо напрямую подключить *bootstrap.less* в ваши *.less* файлы.

Еще одним вариантом будет указание правильно порядка файлов прямо в *Gulp*:

```
gulp.task('bootstrap', function(){
     gulp.src([
        './bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less',
        './bower_components/bootstrap/less/mixins.less',
        // ...
        './bower_components/bootstrap/less/alerts.less',
        './bower_components/bootstrap/less/progress-bars.less',
        './bower_components/bootstrap/less/media.less',
     ])
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Нигде в сети не смог найти ответ. И, похоже, я его даже видел, перед глазами он мелькал, но я его не понял.